# Validate JWT token signed with RS256 in Knock (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jwt, auth0

I am trying to connect React app and Rails app using Auth0. It used to be super simple since tokens were signed with HS256. But since auth.js v8 jwt tokens signed with RS256. I don't have problems with frontend but can't make RoR (I use Knock) work with new signing algorithm. I've added

config.token_signature_algorithm = 'RS256'

and

config.token_public_key = key.public_key

into Knock initializer but still no luck.

Key seems to be correct, at least it works in jwt.io or pure ruby-jwt (at least I was able to read information from token).

I am no expert working with asymmetric algorithms so any help would be appreciated. What I am trying to do right now is to get "access_token" from frontend and to send it in "authorization" header to the backend. I know I need to add "Bearer" into header but is there is any other operation I need to do with token first?

Best, Iurii

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone interested here is short discussion on GitHub here is a [link](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-rubyonrails-api-sample/issues/4)